# LiveCharts - How to prevent the Y-Axis from showing double values?

Tags: wpf, livecharts

I have a Columndiagram. This diagram may have Y values from 0 to very larg numbers.

**My problem:**

When the Y values are small (from my observation smaller than 7), the chart shows double values. (for example: 0, 0.01, 0.02 ... , 0.1), which is in my case not correct.

**What I want:**

force the Y Axis to use integers.

**What I *cannot* do:**

I cannot define a `seperator` for the Y axis and set its `Step` to 1. Becuase if I do it, I'll have `Step= 1` even if the values are very large, which is not desirable.

Is there any workaround for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the library decides the step (when you don't force it) with the `CalculateSeparator()` method (for more info see [this](https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts/blob/master/Core40/AxisCore.cs#L242)), since the library should also allow you to plot decimal values, it can not be forced to display only integers.

A simple work around I can think of, is to force the `Axis.MaxValue` property.

In your case, when your values are less than 7, I would force the `Axis.MaxValue` to `10` (or any other value that works fine for you), then when the data in your chart is greater than 7, you can set `Axis.MaxValue` back to `double.NaN` and the library will calculate this limit by it self.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much! @bto.rdz